# why does git push to Heroku require "looser" router security than Bitbucket? (BOTH use port 22)

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I have two git remotes, Bitbucket and Heroku.

Both remotes are defined to use SSH (eg, git@SERVICE:USER/PROJECT.git style urls)

When doing a `git push` from a new wifi location, pushes to Heroku fail 100% of the time unless I can change the router security level from "medium" to "low". (Pushes to Bitbucket work regardless of the security level.)

Using ssh -vvv I verify that port 22 is always used, which works for Bitbucket but fails for Heroku.

ssh -vvv git@heroku.com shows port 22 fails:

```
# Router set to "medium" security; Bitbucket always works fine...
$ ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/foo/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

```
# Router set to "medium" security; Heroku fails 100% of the time, uses SAME port!
$ ssh -vvv git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/foo/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

```
# Router set to "low" security; Heroku works 100% of the time...
$ ssh -vvv git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/foo/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Why does Heroku depend on a looser router-security than Bitbucket, when they both use SSH (22) for `git push`?

I've had this trouble on multiple routers.

"Low security" (allows push to Heroku) blocks:

```
IDS enabled
IDENT (port 113)
```

"Medium security" (allows push to Bitbucket, Github, NOT Heroku)
enable IDS

```
IDENT (port 113)
ICMP request
Peer-to-peer apps:
kazaa - (TCP/UDP port 1214)
bittorrent - (TCP port 6881-6999)
gnutella- (TCP/UDP port 6346)
vuze - (TCP port 49152-65534)
```

Comment: The question is properly formatted but meaningless. How do we know what low- and medium-security means in you router? May be heroku.com is blacklisted in medium-sec level, or may be bitbucket.org is whitelisted. Or may be they use different SSL algorithms and medium-sec level considers heroku's inadequate.

Comment: The point is I'm using 'git push' to two different sites, BOTH of which remote settings are configured to use the same port 22, ONE of which exhibits some sort of router-specific dependency as to whether it permits the SSL connection. The router has no whitelists or blacklists. But clearly Heroku has SOME additional requirement for a connection that is somehow related to SOME ports aside from 22 that a router might block. Hence the question.